# Check if an array includes an array in the correct offset

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have arrays to compare and one has 4 values and the other one 3 values. Some of them can be null like this for example :

```
[1,2,3]

[null,1,2,3] -> should return true
[1,2,3,null] -> should return true
[1,null,2,3] -> should return true
[1,2,2,3] -> should return false
[null,null,null,null] -> should return true
[1, null, 3, 2] -> should return true
```

In fact, null is working as 1,2,3 at the same time, this is a generic value to define "you can go"

I don't know how to do that in JavaScript but I already tried that :

```js
            let shouldDisplay = colors.every(function(element){
                return element ? neededColors.includes(element) : true;
            });
```

Is it possible to achieve that properly? I could do some crappy checks with functions but it would not be nice

Thanks you!

Comment: `[1, null, 3, 2] -> should return true` what is the reason for this?

Comment: i don't get the difference between `[1,null,2,3] -> should return false` AND `[1, null, 3, 2] -> should return true`. Please be more clear

Comment: if `[1,null,2,3] -> should return false` then why would `[1, null, 3, 2] -> should return true`

Comment: It's not very clear for us, please be more precise

Comment: I guess the OP wants circular comparison [1, null, 3, 2] if is circular would lead to 1,2,3,null but that's wierd

Comment: what would `[1, 2, 3, 2]` return

Comment: @VLAZ since null is working as a generic value, it would be acceptable to ```[1, null, 3, 2]``` to return true since null could be replaced to 2 

@MaximeGirou  @Asthmatic sorry, mistake

[1,2,3,2] would return true

Comment: also for `[1,null,2,3]` being false, does this mean `[1,1,2,3]` would also be false?

Comment: so if there are succesivly 1, 2, 3 (or null values) its ok ?

Comment: null should be interpreted as 1, 2, 3 simultaneously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand properly, the `null` value is like a wildcard, so this should works – although is not very elegant, it might be improved.

```
const element  = [1, 2, 3];

function compare(a, b) {
  let k = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < b.length && k < 3; i++) {
    if (b[i] === null || b[i] === a[k]) {
      k++;
    // this is needed for the `[null, 1, 2, 3]` scenario
    } else if (b[i] === a[0]) {
      k = 1;
    } else {
      k = 0;
    }
  }

  return k === 3
```

And here you can test it:

```
console.log(compare(element, [null, 1, 2, 3])) // true
console.log(compare(element, [1, 2, 3, null])) // true
console.log(compare(element, [1, null, 2, 3])) // false
console.log(compare(element, [1, 2, 2, 3])) // false
console.log(compare(element, [null, null, null, null])) // true
console.log(compare(element, [1, null, 3, 2])) // true
console.log(compare(element, [null, 2, null, 2])) // true
```

Of course it would work with any sequence of elements, for example:

```
console.log(compare(["cc", "22", "fe"], [null, "22", "fe", null]))
```

**EDIT:**
As per comment, there is still one scenario the result is wrong, `[1, null, 2, 3]`: that's because the code above consider only one possible path, so if we're already in the middle of one sequence (`1, null`), the code expects the following item of the sequence (`3`), where, instead, it should understand that `null, 2, 3` is still valid.

I tried to tweak a bit the code above, here the result:

```
function compare(a, b) {
  let last = b[0];
  let k = 0;
  for (let i = 1; i < 4 && k < 3; i++) {
    if (b[i] === a[k] || b[i] === null) {
      last = b[i];
      k++;
    } else if (b[i] === a[k + 1] && (last === null || last === a[k])) {
      last = b[i];
      k+=2;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return k === 3
}
```

This save the last item parsed, and also peek the next one in the sequence: with those information, is able to determine in a better way if the sequence (wildcard included) are i the array.
I hard coded the number of the loop (3 and 4) this time, but it should works also as before.

Let me know if there are other edge cases!

Comment: null is acting as a wildcar in my case. For example, based on the array ```[1,2,3]``` the response ```[1, null, 2, 3]``` should work since the array could be ```[1, 1, 2, 3]```

Comment: Ah, you're totally right! I will try to update my answer with a code that should reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by iterating over the array:

```js
function check(array, pattern){
  //Next index in the pattern
  let index=0
  for(const elem of array){
    if(elem===pattern[index++] || elem === null){
      if(index >= pattern.length)
        return true
    }else{
      //Didn't match, reset index of pattern
      index=0
    }
  }
  return false
}

console.log(check([1,2,null],[1,2,3]) //true
console.log(check([1,2,4,null],[1,2,3]) //false
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to do it is by using join() and indexOf(). Please see below example :

```js
let aOriginalArray = [1,2,3];
let arrayToCompare = [null, 1,2,3]
let isOffset = arrayToCompare.join('').indexOf(aOriginalArray.join('')) > -1;
console.log(isOffset);
```

Comment: I didn't actually understand usage of null in second array. You want to remove them then compare or they are mapped to a value?

Comment: null is acting as a wildcard, this could be every value at that time